# How to find web element by xpath using javascript code in python selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, document.evaluate

I would like to find web element by xpath executing javascript code in python and then click on it. Is this possible and how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To find a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) by [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in you have to use the [`evaluate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate) method which evaluates an *xpath* expression and returns a result.

---

### document.evaluate()

[document.evaluate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) returns an [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult) based on an [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression and other given parameters.

The syntax is:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  xpathExpression,
  contextNode,
  namespaceResolver,
  resultType,
  result
);
```

---

### Example

As an example the *Search Box* within the [Google Home Page](https://www.google.com/) which can be identified uniquely using the *xpath* as `//*[@name='q']` can also be identified from the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) *Console* using `document.evaluate()` and the *xpath* expression as follows:

```
document.evaluate("//*[@name='q']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

Snapshot:

[image: document_evalute_xpath]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following method (check the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)):

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

Then, to click on the element you found, simply use:

```
element.click()
```

Comment: I know I can find web element by using your above code but this is not what I've asked for. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: nice, unless he asks about JAVASCRIPT CODE